# Outlook-VSTO-AddIn Active Inspector Getting Null When Mail Item Loads

Tags: outlook-addin

I am trying to get fetch the mail from the active inspector.

But my Inspector is returning the `null` value. Here is my code:

```
return Globals.ThisAddIn.MailManager.MailByInspector(
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector());
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: When exactly do you access Application.ActiveInspector?

Comment: At  the time of reading the mail from inbox/sent item etc. The Problem only happened when the add-in works on a machine configured under Active Directory.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you doing that in a particular event? Are you sure there is a separate inspector opened? Or is it just in the preview pane?

Comment: Yes, I am opening it in Mail_Open event

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Application.Inspectors.NewInspector` event instead.